# Creating multipe page.tpl for different page groups in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

the site I'm currently building in Drupal is split into two very different areas, both structured quite differently. My solution is to build two different page.tpl pages. Does anyone know what the easiest method is to implement this in Drupal 7. Is it a naming convention process like the node.tpl page or will I need to insert a preprocess function in the template.php page.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Not quite sure why you gave this question a negative point - if you have the answer please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also attach a preprocess function in your template.php file. Something like the following:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {  
    if (isset($vars['node'])) {  
        // If the node type is "blog_madness" the template suggestion will be "page--blog-madness.tpl.php".  
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: judging from the comment in your code it seems like page__foo.php gets magically converted to page--foo.php (underscore to hyphen). Is it always the case in Drupal7?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

It explains the naming schema for your template files and how to extend the template suggestions.

In your case, you'll have to implement the `theme_get_suggestions()` function. In this function you can check the path arguments to determine which kind of page you need to display and add the appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I've taken a look and I can only get a new page.tpl to apply to an individual page not a group of pages.

Comment: I have extended my answer a bit. Please experiment with `theme_get_suggestions()`. The devel module can help you to see which suggestions are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it . If you want to use two different template files then just create two different content types and you can by pass all this coding.

let me know if you need further help.
vishal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module.

Within a given context, you can add the "Template suggestions" reaction.  This will allow you to specify additional template files that will override the defaults.  See the issue in the Context queue, [Add a "Template suggestions" reaction](http://drupal.org/node/2185613), for details.

With this approach, it's not necessary to write any module code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Add specific templates.
  foreach ($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] as $theme_suggestion) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $theme_suggestion . '__' . $node->view_mode;
  }
}
```

also you can call preprocess function here if adding this code

```
  // Run specific preprocess function.
  $preprocess = 'your_theme_preprocess_node_' . $node->type . '__' . $node->view_mode;
  if (function_exists($preprocess)) {
    $preprocess($variables);
  }
```

in this case you can use different templates not only for node types but for different view modes too